# Spivak, Ch. 3 Functions, Problem 12d: Prove every even function $f(x)$ can be written $f(x)=g(|x|)$ for infinitely many functions $g?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem has no solution available in the solution manual. I'd like to check if my solution is correct.

We are asked to prove that every even function $f$ can be written $f(x)=g(|x|)$ for infinitely many functions $g$.

$$f(x)=f(-x)$$

**My solution**

Consider a function $g(x)$ defined as

$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        f(x), & x\geq0 \\
        \text{any function of x} & x < 0 \\
        \end{array}\right\}$$

$$\implies g(|x|)=f(x), \forall x$$

Because we can choose any functional form for $g(x)$ when $x<0$, there are infinitely many functions $g(x)$ that we can come up with such that $f(x)=g(|x|)$.

Comment: Looks good to me!